# Prove that a system is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove the that system

$\begin{cases}
x + 2y - z = a\\
2x +y + 3z = b\\
x - 4y +9z = c
\end{cases}$

is consistent when $c = 2b - 3a$

I am assuming I need to show this with row operation and that the value for c gives a nice indication of what I have to do.

Using elementary row operation I was able to reduce this to

$\begin{bmatrix}
x & 0 & 11z & | & 2b-3a\\
0 & -2y & 10z & | & 2b - 2a
\end{bmatrix}$

Either I made a mistake, or I am using the wrong approach, but I do not think this answer proved anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some mistake, since the [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) presented in the question only has two rows, but there's three equations.

Since we assume $c=2b-3a$, the system of equations is:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
2 & 1 & 3 \\
1 & -4 & 9 \\
\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
a \\
b \\
2b-3a \\
\end{array}\right].$$
or in augmented matrix form
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 2 & -1 & a \\
2 & 1 & 3 & b \\
1 & -4 & 9 & 2b-3a \\
\end{array}\right].$$
Now we can perform row operations as usual.

Comment: There are only 2 rows because I eliminated 1, but looking at your matrix and looking what I have on paper I already see my mistake.

Comment: We'll get an all-zero row, but we shouldn't eliminate it; it's important when discussing rank, nullity, dimension, etc.